# Accessing shadow-root in selenium causing org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: circular reference

Tags: javascript, kotlin, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, shadow-dom

I'm implementing automated tests and I have a web page with a shadow-root that I need to access

I'm trying to do that by using this code:

```
val shadowHost = Browser.findElement(By.id("editor_1"))
val shadowRoot = shadowHost.shadowRoot
```

but is giving me below error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: circular reference
```

I also tried with:

```
val shadowRoot= (Browser.getDriver() as JavascriptExecutor).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", shadowHost)
```

And it throws the same error.

and:

```
val shadowRoot= (Browser.getDriver() as JavascriptExecutor).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot.children", shadowHost)
```

This throws

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: stale element not found
```